# Masstransit saga using redis integration cause exception

Tags: redis, masstransit

I'm tying to use MassTransit sagas in my application using RedisSagaRepository.
Initialization looks like

```
        var machine = new CreditTransactionStateMachine();
        var redisOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
        {
            EndPoints =
            {
                "link-to-redis:6379",
            },
            ClientName = "login",
            Password = "pass",

        };

        var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisOptions);
        var repo = new Lazy<ISagaRepository<CreditTransactionSaga>>(
            () => new RedisSagaRepository<CreditTransactionSaga>(() => redis.GetDatabase()));

        var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
        {
            IRabbitMqHost host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://link-to-rabbit"), h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });

            x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "queueName", e =>
            {
                e.PrefetchCount = 8;
                e.StateMachineSaga(machine, repo.Value);
            });
        });

        busControl.Start();
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Bus started.");
```

So when i get a message in my queue, the state machine starts processing it, but then appears the *NotImplementedByDesignException*.

Full stacktrace is

> Redis saga repository does not support
>   queriesMassTransit.NotImplementedByDesignException: Redis saga
>   repository does not support queries   в
>   MassTransit.RedisIntegration.RedisSagaRepository`1.SendQuery[T](SagaQueryConsumeContext`2
>   context, ISagaPolicy`2 policy, IPipe`1 next)   в
>   MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.QuerySagaFilter`2.>-Send>d__6.MoveNext()---

Looks like the RedisSagaRepository is not supposed to use SendQuery method, but in QuerySagaFilter it explicitly calls, and i see no ways to workaround this.

Is any working examples of initialization of RedisSagaRepository or suggestions how to use it without calling SendQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i found to avoid **RedisSagaRepository.SendQuery** method is
using **EventCorrelationConfigurator.CorrelateById** method instead of **EventCorrelationConfigurator.CorrelateBy** while configure a state machine events.

So it is supposed to have a correlation Guid in all of your models, consuming by state machine. Hope it helps to anyone.

Comment: That's correct, the Redis library doesn't support anything past the primary ID index. Not sure how you'd do it, or if it's possible, I don't use REdis.

Comment: I've not found better way than translate my _long_ id to _Guid_ using as CorrelationId. Hope to write in future another repo to connect my Oracle DB via Linq2DB or something

Comment: Translating long to Guid is a proper way of doing this. The id should be deterministic and should a Guid, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

According to Chris Patterson Masstransit's maintainer, the **saga** is configured with **Redis** as follows.

[repository](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-WebApplicationFactory/blob/master/src/Sample.Api/Program.cs)

[document](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/redis.html#configuration)

```
 builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x => {
 
x.AddSagaStateMachine<OrderStateMachine, OrderState, OrderStateDefinition>()
    .RedisRepository("redis connection string");

 x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
 {
    cfg.Host(massTransitConfig["Host"],
       h =>
       {
           h.Username("Username");
           h.Password("Password");
       }
    );
    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
 });
});
```